# Postponed mikvah and counting

Tags: halacha, mikvah-ritual-bath

A woman that made a Hefsek Tahara and counted for 6 days, but then didn’t count the 7th and didn't go to the Mikvah since she was not going to have sexual relations. Another 10 days passed.

Can she count the 7th day and go to the Mikvah?

Comment: she needs 7 consecutive days of cleanness.

Comment: She should have counted the seventh day and then postponed mikva as she wished.

Answer (score 1):

#### NOTE: this definitely seems like a [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor) case.

---

In the interest of learning, I saw in  [**R' Zvi Sobolofsky**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zvi_Sobolofsky) *shlit"a*'s sefer "[The Laws and Concepts of Niddah](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592643256)", Chapter 26 "Counting the *Shivah Nekiyim*"- a responsum of the [**Me'il Tzedakah**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah_Landsofer)(1678-1712):

[image]

[image]

#### **Practically speaking: this is just academic; one should DEFINITELY [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor)**

Comment: I don't see any evidence in the question that this applies. Where did she have hesech hadas? (There's a better reason she has to restart of course, but you didn't mention it.)

Comment: @DoubleAA which better reason are you referring to?

Comment: When do you expect her to be doing bedikot?

Answer (score 0):

[The Poskim](https://www.sefaria.org/Pitchei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.196.6) in Yoreah Deah 196:4 write that there is not allowed to be more than a 5 day gap in the middle of the shiva nekiyim.

She must start the 7 nekiyim again. However,according to some, a hefsek tehara may not be required.

Answer (score -4):

She needs to count the seven consecutive days and then she can schedule her mikvah bath. To avoid these kinds of mistakes you can use [MikvahCalendar App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=MikvahCalendar.com) which will simplify mikvah calculations and also send you reminders for that.

Comment: This post would be a great deal more valuable if you'd [edit] in [your source](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/answers-when-is-a-source-required) for the halachic assertion in this answer. I noticed that all of your posts to date, as well as your profile, contain links to Mikvah Calendar. Are you affiliated with this app? if so, please note the "Avoid overt self-promotion" section of [our FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and disclose your affiliation wherever relevant.